# not able to use ai.djl.modality.cv.util.BufferedImageUtils in my application

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, artificial-intelligence, djl

> I am new to AI technology .I dded every DJL which are required to my
> project . But when I go to use
> ai.djl.modality.cv.util.BufferedImageUtils. I am not able to import it
> in my project.It show me an error create local variable
> BuffredImageUtils.

```
Unresolved reference: BufferedImageUtils
```

> here all my graddle depedency I added in my Project

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
}

group = "com.main"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation("commons-io:commons-io:2.6")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.djl/api
    implementation("ai.djl:api:0.9.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.djl.tensorflow/tensorflow-api
    implementation("ai.djl.tensorflow:tensorflow-api:0.9.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.djl.tensorflow/tensorflow-engine
    implementation("ai.djl.tensorflow:tensorflow-engine:0.9.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna
    implementation("net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.djl.tensorflow/tensorflow-native-auto
    runtimeOnly("ai.djl.tensorflow:tensorflow-native-auto:2.3.1")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> DJLConfig.kt

```
package com.main.xrayaiapplication.config

import ai.djl.modality.Classifications
import ai.djl.modality.cv.util.NDImageUtils
import ai.djl.ndarray.NDArray
import ai.djl.ndarray.NDList
import ai.djl.translate.Batchifier
import ai.djl.translate.Translator
import ai.djl.translate.TranslatorContext
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage

@Configuration
class DjlConfig{
    class XrayTranslator: Translator<BufferedImage,Classifications> {
        override fun processInput(ctx: TranslatorContext?, input: BufferedImage?): NDList {
            var array: NDArray? = BufferedImageUtils.toNDArray(
                ctx.ndManager, input, NDImageUtils.Flag.COLOR
            )
            array = NDImageUtils.resize(array, 224).div(255.0f)
            return NDList(array)
        }

        override fun processOutput(ctx: TranslatorContext?, list: NDList?): Classifications {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun getBatchifier(): Batchifier {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    }

}
```

I get error exact at this line

var array: NDArray? = BufferedImageUtils.toNDArray(

Not able to access the DJL AI features , and contents

Answer (score 0):

The `BufferedImageUtils` has been removed in newer version fo DJL api. You need to use `ImageFactory` instead:

```
ImageFactory factory = ImageFactory.getInstance();
# Image image = factory.fromFile(Paths.get("..."));
# Image image = factory.fromUrl("...");
Image image = factory.fromImage(bufferedImage);
NDArray array = image.toNDArray(ctx.getManager());
```